# Flutter error 'RenderAspectRatio has unbounded constraints' when row of containers are inside a wrapped Expanded column

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, flutter-layout

In Flutter, I'm attempting to build rows of containers that are inside the `Expanded` wrapped column which is also inside a row. for some reason, it errors on `'RenderAspectRatio has unbounded constraints'`. I've attempted to move the `Expanded` widget to different places on the code but it continues to error sometimes it will throw,

```
"RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded"
```

I've tried many things and I read many Q&A on the issues here in StackOverflow and elsewhere but to no avail, I still haven't solved the problem.

here's the code:

```
      Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          print('Just clicked on 7');
                        },
                        child: Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          child: AspectRatio(
                            aspectRatio: 1,
                            child: Container(
                              color: Colors.yellow,
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                              child: const AutoSizeText(
                                '7',
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 300.0, color: Colors.black45),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          print('Just clicked on 7');
                        },
                        child: Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          child: AspectRatio(
                            aspectRatio: 1,
                            child: Container(
                              color: Colors.yellow,
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                              child: const AutoSizeText(
                                '7',
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 300.0, color: Colors.black45),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          print('Just clicked on 7');
                        },
                        child: Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          child: AspectRatio(
                            aspectRatio: 1,
                            child: Container(
                              color: Colors.yellow,
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                              child: const AutoSizeText(
                                '7',
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 300.0, color: Colors.black45),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          print('Just clicked on 7');
                        },
                        child: Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          child: AspectRatio(
                            aspectRatio: 1,
                            child: Container(
                              color: Colors.yellow,
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                              child: const AutoSizeText(
                                '7',
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 300.0, color: Colors.black45),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  //Expanded(
                  //child:
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      print('Just clicked on 8');
                    },
                    child: AspectRatio(
                      aspectRatio: 1,
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.cyan,
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                        child: const AutoSizeText(
                          '8',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 300.0, color: Colors.black45),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
),
```

);
}

I'm attempting to create something that looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't get the whole idea from the image but from what I understood, I have implemented it like this.

Since there is a lot of repetition and there is a pattern, I use GridView and ListView respectively.

```
class NumbersGridView extends StatelessWidget {
  const NumbersGridView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: GridView.builder(
              gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 4,
                childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
                crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                mainAxisSpacing: 20,
              ),
              itemCount: 30,
              itemBuilder: (buildContext, index) {
                return InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    print(index);
                  },
                  child: AspectRatio(
                    aspectRatio: 1,
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.cyan,
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                      child: AutoSizeText(
                        index.toString(),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: const TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 300.0, color: Colors.black45),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }),
        ),
        Container(width: 20.0, child: VerticalDivider(color: Colors.red)),
        Flexible(
          child: SizedBox(
            width: 50.0,
            child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: 5,
                physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                itemBuilder: (buildContext, index) {
                  return Container(
                    height: 40.0,
                    width: 40.0,
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    color: Colors.cyan,
                    child: AutoSizeText(
                      index.toString(),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black45),
                    ),
                  );
                }),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

If you want to implement it as you originally tried, here's is the code without the specified error.

```
Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                            child: GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                                print('Just clicked on 7');
                              },
                              child: Align(
                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                child: AspectRatio(
                                  aspectRatio: 1,
                                  child: Container(
                                    color: Colors.yellow,
                                    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                                    child: const AutoSizeText(
                                      '7',
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 300.0,
                                          color: Colors.black45),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                                print('Just clicked on 7');
                              },
                              child: Align(
                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                child: AspectRatio(
                                  aspectRatio: 1,
                                  child: Container(
                                    color: Colors.yellow,
                                    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                                    child: const AutoSizeText(
                                      '7',
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 300.0,
                                          color: Colors.black45),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                                print('Just clicked on 7');
                              },
                              child: Align(
                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                child: AspectRatio(
                                  aspectRatio: 1,
                                  child: Container(
                                    color: Colors.yellow,
                                    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                                    child: const AutoSizeText(
                                      '7',
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 300.0,
                                          color: Colors.black45),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                                print('Just clicked on 7');
                              },
                              child: Align(
                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                child: AspectRatio(
                                  aspectRatio: 1,
                                  child: Container(
                                    color: Colors.yellow,
                                    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                                    child: const AutoSizeText(
                                      '7',
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 300.0,
                                          color: Colors.black45),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      //Expanded(
                      //child:
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          print('Just clicked on 8');
                        },
                        child: AspectRatio(
                          aspectRatio: 1,
                          child: Container(
                            color: Colors.cyan,
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                            child: const AutoSizeText(
                              '8',
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 300.0, color: Colors.black45),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )
```

Comment: I was planning to have two columns with different sets of containers in each column. my question was about the column on the left.

Comment: I was able to make it work, I'll update my answer and share the original code.

Comment: great, your second code worked. now another quick question. I want that on the first column the containers will start at the top and on the second column they will be centered.  I used `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,` which I placed right under the top Row. the problem is that it will make everything under in the same alignment but I want that on the second column the containers will be centered. it appears that the `crossAxisAlignment` doesn't work inside the nested rows and columns. any idea how to go about it?

Comment: I have edited my answer, just see the last widget with the number 8. I have used `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center` to center the children of the column.